# EMI analysis for low power low voltage AC/DC

Tags: noise, emc, emi-filtering, common-mode, power-factor-correction

I've designed an 80W 220V-IN 400V-OUT PFC Boost converter in order to analyze its conductive EMI and design the proper active EMI filter for it. but as this is my first implementation project, working with such high values of voltage and wattage is dangerous and expensive. can I reduce the specifications (for example 5W 10V-IN 15V-OUT) from the EMI point of view? I mean, is such a converter have significant EMI issues to suppress by an active filter? and is this research valuable and applicable?
[image]

Comment: Please add a schematic, or an example schematic.

Answer (score 0):

As the components you will choose as well as the dV/dt and di/dt will differ in the two schematics, it is clear that the EMI signature as well as the EMI filter's required attenuation will differ. In particular common mode noise will be much higher with higher output power and dV/dt. Of course, you can design an EMI filter for a 5W converter and it will still improve your EMI signature, but you will most likely need to redesign your EMI filter (because of power dissipation as well as attenuation level).

Comment: of course, I didn't mean reducing the specifications as a model of the bigger one. I want to change the face of the issue. my question is EMI emissions of the 5W converter are considerable or not? and designing an active EMI filter for such a converter is reasonable or not?

Comment: There won't be that much EMI issues using a 5W 10V converter, so designing a full EMI filter is overkill to me. Just a simple LC low-pass would do the trick (for DM only). As mentionned by @Andy aka it depends on the level of noise you want

Comment: let's add that EMI issues are highly dependant on layout so with good practices and without going too crazy with high switching frequencies this should be fine without anything before the SMPS

Answer (score 0):

> *I've designed an 80W 220V-IN 400V-OUT PFC Boost converter in order to
> analyse its conductive EMI and design the proper active EMI filter for
> it*

Give yourself a head start and analyse conducted emissions in a simulator. Pretty reasonable results can be achieved for conducted emissions this way. You can model the LISN and all the meters for measuring the emissions as well as your actual circuit.

So, with a head start, it means you can get reasonably close to the design of any extra filter that is needed before burning your fingers by jumping in the deep end.

> *can I reduce the specifications (for example 5W 10V-IN 15V-OUT) from
> the EMI point of view?*

No, is my best answer to this one; it won't behave anything like what the full power one looks like.

Comment: of course, I didn't mean reducing the specifications as a model of the bigger one. I want to change the face of the issue. my question is EMI emissions of the 5W converter are considerable or not? and designing an active EMI filter for such a converter is reasonable or not?

Comment: Define considerable and reasonable. Your question particularly looks like you want to make a mini version of the real thing and hope to scale your filter up. This is not a method that will bear fruit compared to the much better way of using a simulator.